# How to append text to an existing text file

Tags: vb.net, text, file-writing

I have a program, which writes data to a text file in the following format.

```
test1   -    test1     -     test1     -     test1
```

After writing the first line, the text fields are cleared to make space for another round of user input. Simply said, this is how it should look:

```
test1   -    test1     -     test1     -     test1
test2   -    test2     -     test2     -     test2
test3   -    test3     -     test3     -     test3
```

Here's my code

```
If Not File.Exists(path) Then
    MessageBox.Show("File doesn't exist in the given path", "No File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Exit Sub
Else

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(path)
    reader = File.OpenText(path)
    Dim content As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    reader.Dispose()
    reader.Close()

    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(path)  'this is where the exception occurs
    writer.Write("Origin : " & Trim(loadOrigin) & vbTab & "-" & vbTab)
    writer.Write("Destination : " & Trim(destination) & vbTab & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

    writer.Write(Trim(txtCarrier.Text) & vbTab & "-" & vbTab)
    writer.Write(Trim(txtLocation.Text) & vbTab & "-" & vbTab)
    writer.Write(Trim(txtDest.Text) & vbTab & "-" & vbTab)
    writer.Write(Trim(txtNotes.Text) & vbTab & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

    writer.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Text written to file", "Data Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    clearFields()

End If
```

1. I used `StreamReader` to read the content already inside the text file and reach the end of it to append the new line. However, it shows an **IOException** error with the message **The process cannot access the file 'D:\test.txt' because it is being used by another process**. It does not help even after I **Dispose** and/or **Close** the `StreamReader`. What am I missing here?
2. Would this code fulfill my initial purpose of writing multiple lines to the same text file as I have mentioned above? Do I have to make any changes?

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`reader.Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close.aspx) should close the file and release all resources for it. Try closing the file prior to calling `Dispose` (which according to MSDN is not needed because the `Close` method does that for you.

`Dim writer As New StreamWriter(path, True)` will open the file for appending text. `Dim writer As New StreamWriter(path)` or `Dim writer As New StreamWriter(path, False)` will overwrite the file (if it exists) or create a new file (if it does not exist).

If you are still getting the exception, make sure you don't have the file open elsewhere (like in Notepad).

Comment: I set the `Dim writer As New StreamWriter(path, True)` and it works! That way no need for a `StreamReader` at all in the first place! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

A very handy VB statement is the `Using` statement, which can be applied to all resources implementing `IDisposable`. It ensures that `Dispose()` will be called in any case before leaving the using block. Even when an exception occurs or when the code block is left by `Return` for example. (Unless you pull the plug).

`Dispose()`, in turn, closes the stream.

```
Dim content As String 
Using reader As StreamReader = File.OpenText(Path)
    content = reader.ReadToEnd
End Using

Using writer As New StreamWriter(Path, True) 'True for append mode
    writer.Write("Origin : " & Trim(loadOrigin) & vbTab & "-" & vbTab)
    writer.Write("Destination : " & Trim(destination) & vbTab & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

    writer.Write(Trim(txtCarrier.Text) & vbTab & "-" & vbTab)
    writer.Write(Trim(txtLocation.Text) & vbTab & "-" & vbTab)
    writer.Write(Trim(txtDest.Text) & vbTab & "-" & vbTab)
    writer.Write(Trim(txtNotes.Text) & vbTab & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
End Using
MessageBox.Show("Text written to file", "Data Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
clearFields()
```

Note: `Dim reader As New StreamReader(path)` is obsolete since you assign a new reader immediately afterwards with `reader = File.OpenText(path)`. `Dim reader As StreamReader` would be sufficient.

Note also that it is not necessary to read to the end of the file in order to append more text. The value `True` as second constructor parameter of the `StreamWriter` does this by itself. Unless you need to read the existing content for another reason, you should drop the `StreamReader` part completely.

Comment: yeah, I dropped the `StreamReader`. and yes, I think I'm gonna use `Using` statement. Much easier. Thank you.