# Why is the file being overwritten?

Tags: vb.net, stream, file-writing, wildfire-api

I'm designing a new server application, which includes a subroutine that parses the input into the console window, for example

```
LogAlways("--- CPU detection ---")
```

will be written as:

```
[net 21:8:38.939] --- CPU detection ---
```

This is the subroutine:

```
Public Sub LogAlways(ByVal input As String)
    Dim dm As String = "[net " + Date.Now.Hour.ToString + ":" + Date.Now.Minute.ToString + ":" + Date.Now.Second.ToString + "." + Date.Now.Millisecond.ToString + "] "
    Console.WriteLine(dm + input)
    Dim fName As String = Application.StartupPath() + "\LogBackups\" + Date.Now.Day.ToString + Date.Now.Month.ToString + "" + Date.Now.Year.ToString + ".log"
    Dim stWt As New Global.System.IO.StreamWriter(fName)
    stWt.Write(dm + input)
    stWt.Close()
End Sub
```

This works, but however only the last line of my desired input is written to the file.

Why is this happening, and how can I make it so that it does not overwrite the log file?
This is using the Wildfire Server API.

This is not a duplicate, as the destination question has a different answer which would otherwise not answer this question.

Comment: *I made this question for the endless trail of newbies that ask the same question over and over again.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append text to an existing text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141866/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-text-file)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Nope, read the destination question & its answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs as the StreamWriter has not been told to *append* the output to the end of the file with the parameter set to `True`, Visual Studio actually gives it as a version of the StreamWriter:

[image]

To correctly declare it:

```
Dim stWt As New Global.System.IO.StreamWriter(fName, True)
```

or in the subroutine:

```
Public Sub LogAlways(ByVal input As String)
    Dim dm As String = "[net " + Date.Now.Hour.ToString + ":" + Date.Now.Minute.ToString + ":" + Date.Now.Second.ToString + "." + Date.Now.Millisecond.ToString + "] "
    Console.WriteLine(dm + input)
    Dim fName As String = Application.StartupPath() + "\LogBackups\" + Date.Now.Day.ToString + Date.Now.Month.ToString + "" + Date.Now.Year.ToString + ".log"
    Dim stWt As New Global.System.IO.StreamWriter(fName, True)
    stWt.Write(dm + input)
    stWt.Close()
End Sub
```

*Requires the following to be `Imports`:*

- System.IO
- System.Windows.Forms

It will now correctly write to the end of the file, but however it is noted that `stWt.Close()`'ing the file on *every call* may cause issues, therefore a queuing system may be better:

- Desired log output is inserted into a single-dimensional array
- A `Timer` dumps this array to the log file on every, say, five to ten seconds
- When this is done, the array is cleared